# Using a big collection - Windows 8 DataGrid

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, datagrid

I am working on a Windows 8 Application (C#/XAML).
One of the requirement is to load a collection of words in the DataGrid and we are using the Semantic Zoom option here.

When the collection has more than about 1500 items the application hangs and gives this error:

**+Exception    {"Not enough quota is available to process this command. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070718)"} System.Exception**

Some of the code used:

```
_collection = _readDictionary.GetModeDetailsForModeDetails(modeId);

var query = from item in _collection
            orderby (item.WordName.ToLower())
            group item by item.WordName[0].ToString().ToUpper() into g
            select new { GroupName = g.Key.ToString().ToUpper(), Items = g };

foreach (var g in query)
{
  GroupInfoList<Words> info = new GroupInfoList<Words>();
  info.Key = g.GroupName;

  foreach (var item in g.Items)
  {
    info.Add(item);
  }

  groups.Add(info);
}

bindGroupData.Source = groups;
(semanticZoom.ZoomedOutView as ListViewBase).ItemsSource = bindGroupData.View.CollectionGroups;
```

and this is the XAML Code:

```
 <SemanticZoom  x:Name="semanticZoom" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >
        <SemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView>
            <GridView ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Group.Key}" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" Foreground="Red" FontSize="24"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridView.ItemTemplate>
                <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <WrapGrid ItemWidth="75" ItemHeight="75" MaximumRowsOrColumns="5" VerticalChildrenAlignment="Center" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </GridView.ItemsPanel>
                <GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="4" />
                        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                    </Style>
                </GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
            </GridView>
            </SemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView>
        <SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>
            <GridView x:Name="GrdViewWord" SelectionMode="Multiple" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource bindGroupData}}"  ItemClick="GrdViewWord_ItemClick" SelectionChanged="GrdViewWord_SelectionChanged" Background="#FFE2E2E2" Height="396" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
                <!-- ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource GridViewItemStyle}"   -->
                <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <!--<WrapGrid Orientation="Vertical"  Background="{Binding BG}"/>-->
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </GridView.ItemsPanel>

                <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="20" Width="75"  >
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding WordName}" Tag="{Binding WordID}" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="12" Margin="5,5,0,0" Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Padding="0"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridView.ItemTemplate>

                <GridView.GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle>
                        <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid Margin="10">
                                    <!--Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"-->
                                    <TextBlock Text='{Binding Key}'  FontSize="25" Foreground="Red" Margin="5" />
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>

                        <GroupStyle.Panel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <VariableSizedWrapGrid Orientation="Vertical" Height="300" />
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </GroupStyle.Panel>
                    </GroupStyle>
                </GridView.GroupStyle>
            </GridView>
        </SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>
    </SemanticZoom>
```

Could anyone please help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use virtualization. GridView can easily be virtualized (UI virt. or Data virt.). see [Microsoft Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh780657.aspx) to see what type of virtualization you need.

Comment: used <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" /> and the now the performance have improved.

Answer (score 0):

Syncfusion providing the fastest Data Grid control for WinRT. It supports UI virtualization.

http://www.syncfusion.com/products/winrt/grid

Comment: Thanks..But it is not the default control. we require the default control and not custom based or third party utility

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a big issue with semantic zoom, anything over about 1200 items just does not work.

In the link above for 'Using virtualization with a list or grid' it says 'Grouped data - UI virtualization is not supported for grouped data.'

Semantic zoom uses grouped data so it does not work.

Even Microsoft's own semantic example crash with moiré than 1200 items.

this link may be useful:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/680136e1-67de-4111-824a-fa9f530ffc10/binding-largesets-of-data-to-gridview-is-causing-a-problem